# Desenvolvendo layout para varios tipos de resoluções mobile com Cordova

Tags: android, apache-cordova, android-layout, mobile

Estou desenvolvendo o layout de um aplicativo desenvolvido utilizando o cordova, porem gostaria de saber como desenvolver para os varios tipos de resoluções que existem nos dispositivos mobiles, teria algum tutorial, livro ou vídeo falando sobre este assunto?

Answer (score 0):

A forma mais fácil é utilizar um framework css responsívo e desenvolver como um se fosse um site mesmo.

Você pode utilizar o [Boostrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) se já tiver conhecimento do sistema de grid do mesmo ou utilizar um framework voltado para desenvolvimento de Apps mobile como [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/).

Você também pode desenvolver sem frameworks, utilizando `css media queries`, mas recomendo o uso de um framework.

Sobre vídeo, tutorial ou livro, existe diversos na internet, mas de forma geral no próprio site do framework deve existir um guia e a documentação, que deve ser o suficiente para você entender o funcionamento.

Comment: Eu ouvi falar bem deste Ionic, porem no site deles só ensina como criar um aplicativo com o framework  deles, preciso adicionar o framework deles no meu aplicativo, você já viu algo parecido com isto que preciso?

Comment: Não estou entendo o que você quer fazer, você tem um aplicativo pronto? Basta incorporar o framework deles no seu aplicativo.

Comment: Exatamente isto, o meu aplicativo esta pronto falta apenas a parte visual dele, no site da Ionic eles ensinam a começar um app do zero, não estou entendendo como incorporar o framework deles com o meu app. Poderia me ajudar com isto?

Comment: Olha, como você tem dificuldades no processo de incorporar um framework no aplicativo, recomendo que faça o seguinte: Recrie seu aplicativo utilizando o Ionic, utilize os tutoriais e veja cada passo, incorporando a logíca do seu app da melhor forma possível.